# How to access gitpod react-native locallink running on particular port?

Tags: react-native, gitpod

I am trying to run a simple react-native project on gitpod.io.It work just fine as I wanted to import all library but after successfully running it provides QR CODE and localhost link where I can configure react-native bundle host(tunnel/LAN/local) I try to open link in the browser it is not working showing error.

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
> ws://localhost:19002/fPZreKGJzOC8CcfRgbSWMKtJXrtyvCB2LRn2hvuLrv8/graphql.

[image]

Comment: Would be super helpful if you could share a public repository or gitpod snapshot.

Comment: https://ab168d3e-36b0-404f-bb78-0ae2aecfe434.ws-us02.gitpod.io/#/workspace/react-native-project or https://github.com/sanjeet123456789/react-native-project (import into gitpod)